# Why does sending UDP broadcast packets with TIdUDPClient works only on some devices?

Tags: delphi, indy, broadcast

I am trying to send UDP packets in my local network to all devices and I tried to use the same (FMX) application to send the packets from different devices. But for some reason it works only from some devices, from others not.

Example code:

```
IdUDPClient1.BroadcastEnabled := true;
IdUDPClient1.Broadcast('MyApp Discover Packet', 25168);
```

According to the Indy manual, this shall send the data to the broadcast address `255.255.255.255`.

When I compile this as a mobile app and run it, it does work perfectly from my mobile phone (Android device) on the same network. I verified on my PC with Wireshark that my computer receives the packet. But when I compile the same application as a Windows (64-bit) app and run it on my PC, it doesn't seem to do anything at all. No errors and Wireshark doesn't even show the outgoing packet on the network, like it is never sent. However if I listen on the same port in the same app on PC, I do receive the UDP packets - unlike from my mobile phone, they are just never sent to the network. What do I do wrong?

If it would be better to use the broadcast address of the current sub-network instead (like `192.168.0.255`, for example), what would be the best way to get it? Does Indy provide, for example, a way to list all network adapters with their IP addresses and submasks?

Comment: Router blocking UDP broadcast?

Comment: I thought about that too, but why would it block UDP broadcast packets only from my PC but not from my (Android) mobile phone, which are both on the same network operating under the same router?

Comment: Did you check Windows' built-in firewall?

Answer (score 1):

> would [it] be better to use the broadcast address of the current sub-network instead (like 192.168.0.255, for example)

Yes, especially since some routers actually block general broadcasts on 255.255.255.255 by default, but not subnet-specific broadcasts.

Also, note that UDP broadcasting only works over IPv4. IPv6 doesn't support broadcasting, so you have to use multicasting instead.

> what would be the best way to get it? Does Indy provide, for example, a way to list all network adapters with their IP addresses and submasks?

Yes, it does, via the `TIdStack.GetLocalAddressList()` method of the global `GStack` object, eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdStack;

var
  ...
  List: TIdStackLocalAddressList;
  Addr: TIdStackLocalAddress;
  Addr4: TIdStackLocalAddressIPv4;
  Addr6: TIdStackLocalAddressIPv6;
  I: integer;
begin
  ...
  // you can omit (Inc|Dec)Usage if you have
  // other Indy components already instantiated... 
  TIdStack.IncUsage;
  try
    List := TIdStackLocalAddressList.Create;
    try
      GStack.GetLocalAddressList(List);
      for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
      begin
        Addr := List[i];
        case Addr.IPVersion of
          Id_IPv4: begin
            Addr4 := TIdStackLocalAddressIPv4(Addr);
            // use Addr4.IPAddress and Addr4.SubNetMask as needed...
          end;
          Id_IPv6: begin
            Addr6 := TIdStackLocalAddressIPv6(Addr);
            // use Addr6 as needed...
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      List.Free;
    end;
  finally
    TIdStack.DecUsage;
  end;
  ...
end;
```